# How to show text on a QProgressBar with a busy indicator?

Tags: python, qt, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4

I'd like to show text on a QProgressBar. I'm using `setRange(0, 0)` to display a busy indicator.

```
progressBar = QProgressBar()
progressBar.setFormat('some text')
progressBar.setValue(0)
progressBar.setRange(0, 0)
```

I have to remove `setRange(0, 0)`, otherwise the text is not shown. Is there a way to show both the busy indicator and the text?

Answer (score 1):

After going back and forth with @Onlyjus I finally understood the whole question.  Here is a solution [edited to work in PyQt5]:

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore

class MyBar(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyBar, self).__init__()
        grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()

        self.bar = QtGui.QProgressBar()

        self.bar.setRange(0, 0)

        self.label = QtGui.QLabel("Nudge")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        grid.addWidget(self.bar, 0, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0)
        self.setLayout(grid)

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.bar = MyBar()

        self.setCentralWidget(self.bar)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    win = MainWindow()
    win.show();
    QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Basically it floats a label over the progress bar.

**Here is the original answer I provided**

I will keep it here because it might be helpful anyways.

Use the setFormat method and style sheets.  The following working example shows how.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import os
import time


class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    i = 0
    style =''' 
    QProgressBar
    {
        border: 2px solid grey;
        border-radius: 5px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    '''

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()

        self.bar = QtGui.QProgressBar()
        self.bar.setMaximum(1)
        self.bar.setMinimum(0)

        self.bar.setStyleSheet(self.style)
        self.bar.setFormat("Custom %v units %p % %m ticks")

        self.setCentralWidget(self.bar)


        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update)
        self.timer.start(500) # update every 0.5 sec

    def update(self):
        print self.i
        self.i += 1
        self.i %= 2
        self.bar.setValue(self.i)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    win = MainWindow()
    win.show();
    QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Comment: It appears to be flashing because the state is changing between on/off every 0.5 seconds.  When the bar's value is 1 (100%) the indicator shows full (i.e. the progress ticks fill the whole bar).  When the bar's value is 0 (0%) the indicator clears all of the ticks.  I believe this is what the original question was asking to do.

The bar's value switches between 1 and 0 every 0.5 seconds.

Comment: When the range is set to 0,0, `setRange(0, 0)`, the progressbar goes into 'busy' mode, which is style specific. Generally, this is a bar with a single block that moves from one end of the bar to the other, or bounces back and forth. It does not flash. Try it in QtDesigner.

Comment: Yup, I see what you're saying now.  I mistook busy mode for an 'off/on' indicator not the bar moving left and right

Comment: I just updated my answer with another widget that shows text on top of a progress bar with a scrolling indicator.

Comment: Update works like a charm! I would accept this answer... I tweaked the answer and posted it on gist: https://gist.github.com/onlyjus/d7f99fb16e9e904e3ba0

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the QProgressDialog class. Here is an example:

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

progressbar = QtGui.QProgressDialog(labelText='Some Text...',
                                    minimum = 0, maximum = 0)

progressbar.setWindowTitle('ProgressBar Demo')
progressbar.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't show the text on the progressbar, it shows the text above the progressbar. That's not what I'm looking for.